# Prove that $f_n \to f$ a.e. iff $a_n \to a_0$

Tags: measure-theory, convergence-divergence

Let $\{a_n\}_{n=0}^\infty$ be sequence of real numbers and $(X,M,\mu)$ a finite measure space. Define a sequence of measurable functions $\{f_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ such that $f_n=a_n$ a.e. (almost everywhere) for all $n \geq 1$, and $f(x)=a_0$ for all $x \in X$. Prove that $f_n \to f$ a.e. iff $a_n \to a_0$.

What I did is to take sets $E_n \subset M$ such that $\mu(E_n)=0$ and $f_n=a_n$ in $E_n^c$, and then took $E=\cup_n E_n$, so that $\mu(E)=0$ and $f_n=a_n$ in $E^c$ for all $n$.

Let $F \subset M$ such that $\mu(F)=0$ and $f_n \to f$ in $F^c$. Then $\mu(F\cup E)=0$ and $f_n \to f$ in $(F \cup E)^c$, which means $a_n \to a$. Conversely, if $a_n \to a$, then $f_n \to f$ in $E$, so $f_n \to f$ a.e.

I wonder if my proof is correct since I have the following doubts:

- How do we know that $E^c \neq \emptyset$ or that $(F \cup E)^c \neq \emptyset$? I came to the conclusion that in that case we'd have $\mu(X)=0$, but what happens in that case? Can we talk about the "almost everywhere" property in a space of measure $0$?
- Is the assumption that the space has finite measure necessary? Cause I didn't use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\mu (X)=0$ then $f_n \to f+1$ almost everywhere! (But we cannot have $a_n \to a$ and $a_n \to a+1$ simultaneously).  So the result is not true in this case. It is quite natural to ignore the zero measure in making such statements.

You don't require finiteness of $\mu$. Your argument is correct and it works for any non-zero measure.